# How to pass an argument to a components query (non-static)?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create a component that I later can reuse on my website like so `<TimeToRead id={someId}/>`. My idea was to pass that id further down into the query.

However that does not work and ends up in: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined`. Why is that so and what am I doing wrong here?

Is `createPage(... context: id: someId)` inside `gatsby-node.js` the only way to pass arguments? But that would only apply to templates...

How can I pass arguments to components?

```
import React from "react"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faClock } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const TimeToRead = ({id}) => {
  console.log(id)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} /> {timeToReadQuery.allMarkdownRemark.edges.node.timeToRead} ~ min.
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export const timeToReadQuery = graphql`
  query timeToReadQuery($id: String!) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { id: { eq: $id } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          timeToRead
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default TimeToRead
```

Comment: not gatsby user, so just an assumption [based on docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-vs-normal-queries/#distinguishing-between-static-and-normal-queries): it's a static query so [cannot take variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query)

Comment: there is [open ticket](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482) for adding variables' support in static queries, still opened for a year

Comment: Thx for replying, but my query isn't static from what I can tell

Comment: "In order for Gatsby to handle static and normal queries differently, it looks for 3 specific cases in babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries:" and later "3. Tagged template expressions using the gql tag". I believe it's exact what you do in  `const timeToReadQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gatsby there are two types of queries. Page queries that can be defined in page components only and accept arguments passed as `context` in `createdPage()`  and static queries which don't access variables and can be used in everywhere but are limited to one per file.

If you `TimeToRead` component file is not a page component then you have 2 options:

1. Use [a static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) - you just can't have variables in it.
2. Define a graphql fragment to use into parent page component.

```js
// in child component 
export const remarkTimeToReadFragment = graphql`
fragment RemarkTimeToRead on Query {
  postTimeToRead: markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
    timeToRead
  }
}`
```

```js
// in page component
export const pageQuery = graphql`
query PageQuery($id: String!) {
  ...RemarkTimeToRead
}
`
```

This particular example may produce a warning because $id param is not used directly in the page query and the linter just won't account for it being used by the fragment.